# How to not overlapping with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to get a layout like this:
[image]

OK, I want the scroll to begin at the end of the first imageview and I want the scroll to finish at he start of the second imageview. I mean, I don't want imageviews to overlap the scroll. I don't know if I've explained well.
First I tried with LinearLayout but I can't align at the bottom the second ImageView. With RelativeLayout, ImageViews overlap the scroll, I can set margin-top to the scroll to solve the problem with the first ImageView, but I don't know how to solve the problem wit the second ImageView.
I also tried to use a RelativeLayout inside the LinearLayout like this:

> <LinearLayout ....>
>       <ImageView ...></ImageView>
>       <ScrollView...></ScrollView>
>       <RelativeLayout...>
>       <ImageView....></ImageView>
>       </RelativeLayout>
>       </LinearLayout>
>   
> The second ImageView doesn't appear. I guess scroll is overlapping it.
>   
> I Would appreciate any help. Thanx you.

Comment: How can I add code like the 1 below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewBottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTop"
        android:background="#006600" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is THE RIGHT answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, put your ListView below imageview1 and above imageView2.
Make sure to use a relativelayout as a parent.

Comment: Put the ImageView2 at bottom (android:layout_alignParentBottom=true), and put ImageView1 at top (android:layout_alignParentTop=true). Put your listview below imageview1 and above imageview2

Comment: there is another horible solution with scroll headre,but I don't recommend it. this is the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/topView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:text="top view" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
      android:layout_below="@+id/topView"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="bottom view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```